# How to show if $x(t)=e^{\sin(t)}$ it is periodic or not?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

$$x(t)=e^{\sin(t)}$$

I have an idea about the way to show this is periodic, that is show $x(t+T) = x(t)$ and $T$ here is the period, but it is hard me to show $x(t+T) = e^{\sin(t)}$

Comment: $x(t)$ is positive so it has the same periodicity as $\ln{(x(t))}$ which is just $\sin{(t)}$ i.e. periodic with fundamental period $2\pi$.

Comment: Can you show that $x(t)=x(t+2\pi)$?

Comment: Hint: what is $\exp(\sin(t + 2\pi))$?

Answer (score 2):

For all $t \in \mathcal{R}$,

$$ x(t+2\pi) = e^{\sin(t+2\pi)} = e^{\sin(t)} = x(t) $$

Therefore, this function is periodic with period $T = 2\pi$.

Comment: I'd add that in general, when you compose two functions, if the "inner" function is periodic, the composition is also. Composing these two functions the other way, i.e. $\sin(e^{t})$ is not periodic.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\sin(t)$ is periodic, and that is the only term dependent on $t$. So what happens when $T$ is equal to the period of $\sin(t)$?